# Can one processes have a descriptor that is non-blocking while another process have a descriptor referencing the same file/socket that is blocking?

Tags: io, unix-sockets, syscalls

I am more interested in sockets than regular files, but basically I want to know whether one process can "see" a socket as blocking where another process can see it as non-blocking.  I am guessing yes, and that the kernel handles all of this depending on what options were used in the syscall.

I guess this would be more about Unix domain sockets than TCP sockets since I don't think 2 different processes could use the same TCP socket (but I could be wrong)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You guess wrong.

The **only** property which is per-file descriptor and which can be changed with `fcntl(F_SETFD)` is the `FD_CLOEXEC` close-on-exec flag.

All the other properties are either per file object ("open file description" in POSIX lingo -- which can be changed with `fcntl(F_SETFL)`), or per inode.

Setting the non-blocking flag with `fcntl(F_SETFL, | O_NONBLOCK)` or with `ioctl(FIONBIO)` will affect all the file descriptors that refer to that open file. There is also no way to make a file non-blocking only for reading or writing.

This is **far** from ideal -- you can also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53673808/10306503) Q&A on StackOverflow, especially the link to the lkml [discussion](https://lkml.org/lkml/2007/8/14/135) about a failed attempt to fix it somehow.

Notice that regular files are basically non-blocking -- a `poll(2)` or `select(2)` on them will return immediately.

If you're only interested in sockets, you should use `send(2)` or `recv(2)` with the `MSG_DONTWAIT` flag instead of `read(2)` or `write(2)`. Contrary to what you say, a socket file descriptor can be shared between processes, and no matter what its family/protocol/options are. And that also applies to a listening socket.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Changing one file descriptor in a process to blocking or non-blocking does not affect other file descriptors of the same or other processes. O_NONBLOCK is a property of a file descriptor, not of the file or socket.</strike> I misremembered. To avoid that one has to open files twice (instead of dup/fork) or create sockets twice.

And different processes can use the same TCP socket. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670891/is-there-a-way-for-multiple-processes-to-share-a-listening-socket). They can even write into the same socket, if they are synchronized correctly.